# nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9801]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am facing this issue in latest iOS version till last version it was working fine(Even runs as expected).

Can you please suggest what could be the issue?

I have added plist settings as well as expected (Please correct if wrong)

```
<dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
  </dict>
```

I have wasted almost 2 days any help will save my another day(s)

Answer (score 3):

** EDIT **

I solved this problem updating my TLS version from 1.0 to 1.2 (in my server). In iOS 10, the minimum TLS Version that works is 1.2.

Font: https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/

---

Same problem here, with iOS 10

im getting the following error: nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9824]

its an iOS bug?

Comment: tls version conflict causes this problem, tls version supported by user backend server is not same with the tls version specified in your info.plist file for your backend url.            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string> <code>